# Functionality of write command in linux

Tags: linux, unix

Suppose I'm using the write command to send messages to another host on the server. Can the root user or any other user get to know that we are interacting?

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done by any user that can capture packets on the interface (including root) and any intermediary devices. Moreover, root could in theory install additional mechanisms to  hijack/inspect traffic.

Comment: So is there a pre installed tool for that in linux or do we need to program a tool like that?

Comment: @RahulChitta The typical tool is probably `tcpdump`.